# Error in downloading files from file server with Spring-Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, smb

Following the Spring guidelines, I was trying to use a SmbOutboundGateway from the spring-integration-smb library to download everything (whole structure, directory + files) at the remote file server specified by the SessionFactory.
Ref.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/smb.html#using-the-mget-command 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/smb.html#outbound-gateway-java-dsl

However when I try to run the flow, it failed in between.

**Source**

```
import jcifs.DialectVersion;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.smb.dsl.Smb;
import org.springframework.integration.smb.dsl.SmbOutboundGatewaySpec;
import org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbSessionFactory;

import java.io.File;

@Configuration
public class SmbConfig {

    @Bean
    public SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory() {
        SmbSessionFactory smbSession = new SmbSessionFactory();
        smbSession.setHost("myhost");
        smbSession.setPort(445);
        smbSession.setDomain("mydomain");
        smbSession.setUsername("myusername");
        smbSession.setPassword("mypassword");
        smbSession.setShareAndDir("pccommon/Patrick/");
        smbSession.setSmbMinVersion(DialectVersion.SMB210);
        smbSession.setSmbMaxVersion(DialectVersion.SMB311);
        return smbSession;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "testChannel")
        void test(String path);
    }

    @Bean
    public SmbOutboundGatewaySpec downloadFileGateway() {
        return Smb.outboundGateway(smbSessionFactory(),
                        AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "payload")
                .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                .localDirectory(new File("" +
                        "/media/sf_linuxshare/Test"));
    }

    @Bean
    public SmbOutboundGatewaySpec uploadFileGateway() {
        return Smb.outboundGateway(smbSessionFactory(),
                        AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MPUT, "'/'")
                .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                .regexFileNameFilter(".*\\.xml$")
                .remoteDirectoryExpression("'/uploaded'");
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("testChannel")
                .handle(downloadFileGateway())
                .handle(uploadFileGateway())
//                .channel(c -> c.queue("uploadFileOutputChannel"))
                .get();
    }
}
```

**Objective**

I was expecting that any folders and underlying files under the remote file server would be copied to local after the download flow, i.e. having the following as a result:
/media/sf_linuxshare/Test/Test_From_Remote/a.xml
/media/sf_linuxshare/Test/Test_From_Remote/b.xml

**Before run**
[image]

**After run (actual result)**
[image]

**Observations**

1. It complained that the target files are not files

Caused by: java.io.IOException: [a.xml] is not a file.

```
    2023-12-04 17:27:46.225  INFO 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2023-12-04 17:27:46.225  INFO 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2023-12-04 17:27:46.226  INFO 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
    2023-12-04 17:27:46.354  INFO 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.i.smb.session.SmbSessionFactory      : SMB share init: hprifil0005.corp.auspost.local:445/pccommon/Patrick/
    2023-12-04 17:27:53.008  WARN 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.i.smb.outbound.SmbOutboundGateway    : File name pattern must be '*' when using recursion
    2023-12-04 17:27:53.069  INFO 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.integration.smb.session.SmbSession   : Successfully listed 1 in [null].
    2023-12-04 17:27:53.141  INFO 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.integration.smb.session.SmbSession   : Successfully listed 2 in [./Test_From_Remote//].
    2023-12-04 17:27:53.331  WARN 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] a.c.a.c.c.e.CustomRestExceptionHandler   : 0a8315f8-9547-4f44-969a-02f292be017f org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=, headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, errorChannel=, id=026be840-5e21-32c1-c894-b6759f40c043, timestamp=1701671266279}]

    org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.get(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1135)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.getRemoteFileForMget(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1289)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.mGetWithRecursion(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1251)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.mGet(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.lambda$doMget$9(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:691)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:452)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doMget(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:690)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:586)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:327)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:151)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:467)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:669)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:584)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:550)
        at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:540)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy78.test(Unknown Source)
        at au.com.auspost.cbg.web.controller.HealthCheckController.mobilestarHealthCheck(HealthCheckController.java:134)
        at au.com.auspost.cbg.web.controller.HealthCheckController.createHealthCheckText(HealthCheckController.java:84)
        at au.com.auspost.cbg.web.controller.HealthCheckController.healthCheck(HealthCheckController.java:67)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:289)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:738)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: [a.xml] is not a file.
        at org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbSession.read(SmbSession.java:204)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.get(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:1124)
        ... 130 common frames omitted

    2023-12-04 17:27:53.392  WARN 26615 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=, headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, errorChannel=, id=026be840-5e21-32c1-c894-b6759f40c043, timestamp=1701671266279}]]
```

2. It tried to rename the target files (it suffixed it with the containing folder name) which I am not sure why this was performed.
i.e. it renamed the files to "a.xmlTest_From_Remote", "b.xmlTest_From_Remote"


Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8800.

Will be fixed in the next version.

As a workaround you can try to implement this `MGET` functionality yourself using `SmbRemoteFileTemplate`.

On the other hand you can try to use the whole remote directory name instead of empty input as you have right now. That's, essentially, how we have missed the problem with plain file name for SMB instead of expected with sub-directories when we fetch recursively.

When we have a this or that fix for the MGET, let's chat about `MPUT` part in a separate SO thread!